# Run function after "Save Draft" but don't run if it autosaveDraft?

Tags: craft4, events

Since **CRAFT_AUTOSAVE_DRAFTS=false** was deprecated in Craft 4, and actually this method also affect some Craft functionality. i want to know if there another method or event that will run myfunction when i saving draft but not when it was autosaveDraft.

i have tried this code:

```
Event::on(
        Entry::class,
        Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
        function (ModelEvent $event) {
            $entry = $event->sender;

            if (ElementHelper::isDraftOrRevision($entry)){
                # some function
            }
```

but my function still run when autosaveDraft is triggered(field content change).

Thank :D